# Does MSN/Hotmail support OAuth?

Tags: oauth, hotmail, windows-live

I want to allow users on my website to import contacts from their hotmail account, using OAuth. Is it possible?

Comment: Take a look @ these webpages. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff752204.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff750546.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Looks like that thing is in beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Microsoft is working on this at the moment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/ff688938.aspx

They already have the OAuth WRAP (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff750690.aspx) library that you can use to connect Windows Live services, however it is in beta and is not freely available (you must join the beta program).

Anyone has any info on how long might this take?

Answer (score 1):

We wrote up a detailed timeline of all of the changes that have happened over Microsoft regarding their contacts API and OAuth here:

http://www.cloudsponge.com/news/2013/11/29/300-percent-increase-in-outlook.com-import-conversions/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff749458.aspx. I've tried to get my "MSN Invite contacts" function working right now and that's what I've found this far. Works excellent!

Answer (score 0):

Playing with hotmail OAuth:
http://pmsenthilkumar.blogspot.jp/2012/01/playing-with-hotmail-oauth.html
(Links to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243649.aspx)